# Let entity have several passengers

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm programming a spectator mode plugin, but I have a problem.

I'm trying to make that if a spectator interacts with a player, then he should become a passenger of it.

But with my implementation, only one player can ride another.
How do I make it possible for two spectators to ride the same player?

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractEntity(PlayerInteractEntityEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    if(plugin.spectating.contains(p)) {
        if(e.getRightClicked() instanceof Player) {
            Player target = (Player) e.getRightClicked();
            if(plugin.alive.contains(target)) {
                target.setPassenger(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I mean for Bukkit/Spigot 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the relatively new vanilla spectator game mode you don't have to make the spectator a passenger of the target player or entity. If the spectator is in game mode #3 (GameMode.SPECTATOR) you can use `player.setSpectatorTarget(Entity entity)` to make the spectator's view follow the target's view (I'm assuming this is what the server you mentioned implemented). Unless you want to have the spectator remain in a different game mode while spectating this should work very well, as multiple players can spectate the same entity at the same time with the built in spectator game mode.

In earlier versions of Bukkit with no built in spectator game mode you can still have multiple players spectate an entity by sending "fake" packets to the client to tell the player to attach to a specified entity. Since the server can only officially keep track of one passenger per entity, it won't know about the other clients/players that are now all behaving as if they were a passenger of the entity, which can cause strange behavior. You need to keep track of all spectators and the entity which they are spectating on the server side, and handle things such as logouts yourself (when the spectators log back in they won't be attached to the entity anymore). Here is a method that attaches a player to an entity, although only on the player's client.

```
public static void setFakePassenger(Player spectator, Entity target) {
    EntityPlayer nmsSpectator = ((CraftPlayer) spectator).getHandle();
    PacketPlayOutAttachEntity attachPacket = new PacketPlayOutAttachEntity(0, nmsSpectator, ((CraftEntity) target).getHandle()); // The packet that tells a client to attach to an entity
    nmsSpectator.playerConnection.sendPacket(attachPacket); // Send packet to client
    // spectators is a HashMap<UUID, Entity> so that we can keep track of which players are spectating which entities
    spectators.put(spectator.getUniqueId(), target);
}
```

With this hack, other players also won't see the spectators move anymore (provided they see them at all without some kind of invisibility) and I have not been able to implement something that allows spectators to dismount or detach themselves from the targets using the regular shift key (other methods might work though).

Comment: Yes, but I mean for the 1.7... Is that possible or not?

Comment: It might very well be possible to "fake" a player's client into thinking they are a passenger of another entity by sending them your own packet, thus allowing multiple players to be the passenger of the same entity. The server will not actually know that the other players are passengers since it can only keep track of one passenger for each entity, which might cause it to be confused about the movement of the other spectators or "passengers" etc., but it might work, I'll look into it!

Comment: Thank you. Because I saw that once on a SurvivalGames server, that 2 people where on the same player.

Comment: Edited my answer for 1.7 support! You'll have to track some things though to remove some bugs/behaviors and make it work as seamlessly as possible. Do you by any chance remember how the 1.7 server let spectators dismount from the targets?

Comment: Let me know if you run into any trouble with the 1.7 method above.

Comment: Well it was just a passenger so like in a boat you had to press Shift

Comment: I have an idea... Everything would be possible, if i make a chicken or a bat everytime a spectator rightclickes the player, set the chicken with your method on the player and the player on the chicken. Or won't that work, because it's then just for the chicken who is on the player and for the others the chicken don't moves?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92592/discussion-between-adrian-sohn-and-nicola-uetz).